# Perform SELECT statement on another SELECT using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-core

In my .NET Core app, I have the following in LINQ:

```
 return  await db.ApplicationUsers.Where(u=>u.Name.Contains(name) && !u.Deleted && u.AppearInSearch)
                                    .OrderByDescending(u => u.Verified)
                                    .Skip(page * recordsInPage)
                                    .Take(recordsInPage)
                                    .Select(u => new UserSearchResult()
                                    {
                                        Name = u.Name,
                                        Verified = u.Verified,
                                        PhotoURL = u.PhotoURL,
                                        UserID = u.Id,
                                        Subdomain = u.Subdomain
                                    }).ToListAsync();
```

which translates to the following SQL:

```
 SELECT [t].[Name], [t].[Verified], 
        [t].[PhotoURL], [t].[Id], 
        [t].[Subdomain]  
 FROM 
      (SELECT [u0].*      
       FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [u0]      
       WHERE (((CHARINDEX('khaled', [u0].[Name]) > 0) OR ('khaled' = N''))
         AND ([u0].[Deleted] = 0)) 
         AND ([u0].[AppearInSearch] = 1)      
       ORDER BY [u0].[Verified] DESC      
       OFFSET 10 ROWS 
       FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY  ) AS [t]
```

But due to performance issues, Microsoft support suggested that I only query columns of fixed length (not varchar(max)). I was asked to change the SQL query to:

```
  SELECT [t].[Name], [t].[Verified], 
         [t].[PhotoURL] , [t].[Id], [t].[Subdomain]
  FROM 
        (Select u0.Name, u0.Verified, u0.PhotoURL, u0.id, u0.Subdomain,
             u0.Deleted, u0.AppearInSearch FROM [AspNetUsers] ) As [u0]
  WHERE (((CHARINDEX('khaled', [u0].[Name]) > 0) OR ('khaled' = N'')) 
    AND ([u0].[Deleted] = 0)) 
    AND ([u0].[AppearInSearch] = 1) 
  ORDER BY [u0].[Verified] DESC      
  OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY  ) AS [t]
```

Which is a SELECT on another SELECT. Unfortunately I don't know how to do it in LINQ. Can someone please guide me how to make the second SQL query in LINQ?

Thank you

Comment: First of all, I would check execution plans of both queries in the profiler. I doubt there's any difference.

Comment: What's the difference between those 2 sql queries? First is select on another select and second one is the same.

Comment: There only difference I noticed is that * in the sub-select is replaced with the strict list of columns. I'm pretty sure that will have totally NO effect on the SQL server query execution plan.

Comment: I agree with @JustAndrei . I woud be very surprised if the second query was any faster / more efficient than the other. The query optimiser will automatically treat the former as the latter anyway.

Comment: @JustAndrei I need to translate the SQL query to LINQ. Please advise if you can.

Comment: It totally makes not sense. However, you may try to add another projection before Where or move existing projection there.

Comment: @JustAndrei It's Microsoft Support's suggestion to make sure that I only query columns of fixed length (not varchar(max)). Kindly provide your suggestion as an answer with code. Thank you

Comment: But you effectively query only those 5 columns, which are in the parent select. The asterisk in sub-select doesn't mean SQL server will process all the columns. It will only load those ones, which are mapped to the parent select columns.

Comment: @JustAndrei are you sure about that as I received this request from support?

Comment: At least if it's executed on MS SQL server, I'm pretty sure the query optimizer cares about that.

Comment: @JustAndrei is correct - I believe MS support have given you a poor suggestion here. Can you give us some context as to why they gave you that suggestion (did you ask them for support? why?)? Also, can you show us the CREATE TABLE script for that table? Also, give us an idea of how many records are in it?

Comment: @mjwills full story here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333703/sql-query-continues-running-for-a-very-long-time-if-search-term-not-found?noredirect=1#comment75675988_44333703 , please ignore this question.

Answer (score 1):

First build the inner select:

```
var s1 = from u in db.AspNetUsers
          select new UserSearchResult
          {
              Name = u.Name,
              Verified = u.Verified,
              PhotoURL = u.PhotoURL,
              UserID = u.Id,
              Subdomain = u.Subdomain
         };
```

then use it in the outer select:

```
 return  await (from u1 in s1 
                where u.Name.Contains(name) && !u.Deleted && u.AppearInSearch
                orderby u.Verified
                select u1)
                 .Skip(page * recordsInPage)
                 .Take(recordsInPage);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Should I perform the where !u.Deleted & u.AppearInSearch in the first selection? as I think that the outer select will not find them in the inner select. Thanks.

Comment: I have implemented the following way and discovered the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333703/sql-query-continues-running-for-a-very-long-time-if-parameter-is-not-available Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you make the output of select query `.ToList()`, the output is a list again. Over this list you can apply another `.Select()`. So, as in your previous query, you can do it as:

```
 return  await db.ApplicationUsers.Where(u=>u.Name.Contains(name) && !u.Deleted && u.AppearInSearch)
                                .OrderByDescending(u => u.Verified)
                                .Skip(page * recordsInPage)
                                .Take(recordsInPage)
                                .Select(u => new UserSearchResult()
                                {
                                    Name = u.Name,
                                    Verified = u.Verified,
                                    PhotoURL = u.PhotoURL,
                                    UserID = u.Id,
                                    Subdomain = u.Subdomain
                                })
                                .ToList()
                                .Select(<your new query>)
                                .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: This answer is about post-processing of the result, so it has nothing about the question, which was about the SQL query the LINQ code is translated to.

Comment: @JustAndrei In fact, I'm looking for the LINQ that would match the second SQL query