# SQL Query continues running for a very long time if search term not found

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-core

In my Azure hosted ASP.NET Core site I have a table of users and I implemented search as follows:

```
    var inner = from user in db.Users
             select  new
             {
                 Name = user.Name,
                 Verified = user.Verified,
                 PhotoURL = user.PhotoURL,
                 UserID = user.Id,
                 Subdomain = user.Subdomain,
                 Deleted=user.Deleted,
                 AppearInSearch = user.AppearInSearch
             };
    return await inner.Where(u=>u.Name.Contains(name)&& !u.Deleted && u.AppearInSearch)
                                    .OrderByDescending(u => u.Verified)
                                    .Skip(page * recordsInPage)
                                    .Take(recordsInPage)
                                    .Select(u => new UserSearchResult()
                                    {
                                        Name = u.Name,
                                        Verified = u.Verified,
                                        PhotoURL = u.PhotoURL,
                                        UserID = u.UserID,
                                        Subdomain = u.Subdomain
                                    }).ToListAsync();
```

This translates to a SQL statement similar to the following:

```
SELECT [t].[Name], [t].[Verified],
       [t].[PhotoURL], [t].[Id], 
       [t].[Subdomain], [t].[Deleted], 
       [t].[AppearInSearch]  
FROM (      
        SELECT [user0].[Name], [user0].[Verified], 
               [user0].[PhotoURL], [user0].[Id], 
               [user0].[Subdomain], [user0].[Deleted], 
               [user0].[AppearInSearch]      
        FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [user0]
        WHERE (((CHARINDEX('khaled', [user0].[Name]) > 0) OR ('khaled' = N'')) 
          AND ([user0].[Deleted] = 0)) 
          AND ([user0].[AppearInSearch] = 1)      
        ORDER BY [user0].[Verified] DESC      
        OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY  ) AS [t]
```

If the search term is available in the database, the result is obtained in less than a second.
**However, If it's not found the query runs for a very long time (I have seen it once reaching 48 seconds).**

This greatly affects performance when we publish this feature to the internet.

Can you kindly suggest a way to solve this issue?

Thank you

Update: this issue is continued here: [Empty Login Name When Showing sys.processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44393287/empty-login-name-when-showing-sys-processes)

Comment: Have you looked at EXPLAIN PLAN for instances that take a long time to run? I'll guess that the column is indexed but does not have a NOT NULL constraint applied. If so, try applying a NOT NULL constraint, substituting a magic string like 'UNKNOWN' for existing NULLs.

Comment: @KevinPostlewaite In fact it is a not null column. execution is not a problem if the term is available.

Comment: Hmmm, it sounds like it's doing a full table scan in case it's not finding the term in the index, which is the case when the term doesn't exist at all. Are you using a standard btree index or is it a different type of index? Can you get the actual execution path for the case where the term is not found? Have you used EXPLAIN PLAN to confirm that it's using the index that you expect?

Comment: it's only using index for verified but not name as it's a Contain() method in LINQ @KevinPostlewaite

Comment: Do you get the same problem when you do a synchronous query (ToList() instead of ToListAsync() and without the await)?

Comment: Are you using EF Core 1.0 or 1.1?

Comment: There is an [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/474) related to pre `1.1.0-preview1` EF Core and another (similar one) with [.StartsWith](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7429) but may be related (affects 1.0 and 1.1, fixed in 2.0 preview)

Comment: @Tseng does this apply to contains()?

Comment: First issues yes, second not sure (as it's stated about .StartWith). First one was fixed in EF Core 1.1 though. But I don't know which one you are using

Comment: @JamesCurran I think that this is not related as the SQL query on ssms faces the same problem.

Comment: I think its an query generator issue that makes it slow in certain conditions, i.e. if you replace `WHERE (((CHARINDEX('khaled', [user0].[Name]) > 0) OR ('khaled' = N'')) ` with `WHERE [user0].[Name] LIKE N'%khaled%')` ? Is it still slow when not found? If it runs faster, try running against EF Core 2.0 preview

Comment: You can't do it in LINQ. Just modify the Query which you logged with the SSDT, just to validate it's on the generated code. If it runs faster, then there may be a bug/issue with the code generation and unless 2.0 preview fixed that already you'd need to open an issue on github. In EF 2.0 you can explicitly do an Like (w/o .Contains), but that's not available in older versions)

Comment: EF Core 2.0 would offer more fine grained usage of like, i.e. `EF.Functions.Like` as in `var customers = from c in context.Customers where EF.Functions.Like(c.Name, "a%"); select c`, instead of relying on `c.Property.Contains("...")`

Comment: @Tseng I tried it with like but the same problem appeared, however if I remove offset and next it runs pretty fast yet I can't do it as it will continue searching if a match is found. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Tseng btw, it's EF 1.1.1 Thanks

Comment: The comment above is correct.  They query is always doing a full table scan, so if the term isn't found it has to scan the whole table.  If it is found it will return the first page size (=10) matching rows.  If you add an index on Name and change your query to .StartsWith you should see it always completes quickly.

Comment: @Phil Thanks. I still need to use contains or  %like% as I want it to find not only starting characters.

Comment: How many rows are in your AspNetUsers table?

Comment: @Phil Around 7 million. Please note that if I remove paging (skip and take) searching for terms that are not in the table happens very fast

Comment: try moving .ToList() in front of skip/take and ensure the search term is long enough (say 3+ chars) to ensure the query doesn't return too many rows.

Comment: @Phil Unfortunately this solution will make returning search results very very slow as with the millions of users and similarity of names, the search will take a very long time.

Comment: @Phil  I have tried like (abc%) but sadly the problem remains.

Comment: @Tseng I have tried LIKE as raw sql but as soon as I deploy to site with many users the problem happens

Comment: If you run the query in SSMS does that take a long time?  Have you run it through SQL query analyzer and applied any recommended indexes?

Comment: @Phil I also see that query analyzer is not available any more, however I saw the execution plan and it uses the index. It runs very smoothly on ssms but not with code...

Comment: Sorry I meant 'database engine tuning advisor'.  This sounds exactly like a problem we had recently.  SSMS runs in < 1 sec.  Linq takes > 1 minute.  All down to SQL messing up the query plan.  Use the tuning advisor, try different indexes.

Comment: @Phil unfortunately it says Azure SQL doesn't support database tuning advisor... We have however tried multiple indexing strategies even suggested by MS but no luck

Comment: that's the first time you mentioned Azure - I'm out of ideas

Comment: @Phil Sorry about that, I have edited the question.

Comment: @Phil I'm starting to think it's a webapp issue as MS say we reach maxconnections although the max pool is less than allowed max connections

Comment: @Phil please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44393287/empty-login-name-when-showing-sys-processes

Answer (score 0):

Already you can simplify your query like this ;) :

```
int start=page * recordsInPage;

var inner = (from user in db.Users
            where user.Name.Contains(name) && !user.Deleted && user.AppearInSearch
            orderby user.Verified descending
            select  new
                   {
                     Name = user.Name,
                     Verified = user.Verified,
                     PhotoURL = user.PhotoURL,
                     UserID = user.Id,
                     Subdomain = user.Subdomain,
                     Deleted=user.Deleted,
                     AppearInSearch = user.AppearInSearch
                   }
             ).Skip(start).Take(recordsInPage);

return await inner.ToListAsync();
```

If you have a performance problem, try to create a stored procedure with your  SQL and use it with entity Framework.

Comment: Thanks. It was similar to this but MS Support suggested querying only fixed-length columns.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has to use a scan to find rows matching the .Contains clause.  There is no way around this.

However, if we reduce the amount of data that SQL server has to scan, we will speed up the query.

### Covering filtered index

An index is "covering" if it contains all the data needed to be returned in a query.

```
CREATE INDEX IX_User_Name_filtered ON USER ([Verified], [Name]) 
INCLUDE ( [PhotoURL], [Id], [Subdomain], [Deleted], [AppearInSearch]  ) 
WHERE [AppearInSearch]=1 AND [Deleted]=0
```

This index is likely substantially smaller than the original table, so even if a scan is required, it will be quicker.

Depending on the plan that is generated, this index may be a better choice.  it doesn't include the extra columns and will be smaller still.  Testing will be required to determine the best choice.

```
CREATE INDEX IX_User_Name_filtered ON USER ([Verified], [Name]) 
WHERE [AppearInSearch]=1 AND [Deleted]=0
```

Comment: we have tried something similar, please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44393287/3453517

Comment: Have you tried adding the above indexes?  The other question you referenced is a symptom of this query performing poorly.  Address this first and the other question becomes a non-issue.

Comment: I have done that this morning.The issue is becoming very weird and I tried many indexes.