# Empty Login Name When Showing sys.processes

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-core

As per the issue here:
[SQL Query continues running for a very long time if search term not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333703/sql-query-continues-running-for-a-very-long-time-if-search-term-not-found)

I faced an issue that my Azure website hits 100% DTU very fast as soon as I publish the search feature to the public.

After further investigation, I ran the following query to show all processes on my database:

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName, 
    COUNT(dbid) as NumberOfConnections,
    loginame as LoginName
FROM
    sys.sysprocesses
WHERE 
    dbid > 0
GROUP BY 
    dbid, loginame
```

The weird thing is that **in addition to the row which has my login name used in the connection string** in my webapp, I see another line which shows empty login name and it has many connections which increase greatly if I enable the search feature.
[image: processes with empty login name]

Can someone please explain the empty login name?

Thank you

Update:
I was also able to run the following query:

```
    SELECT
    c.session_id, c.net_transport, c.encrypt_option,
    s.status,
    c.auth_scheme, s.host_name, s.program_name,
    s.client_interface_name, s.login_name, s.nt_domain,
    s.nt_user_name, s.original_login_name, c.connect_time,
    s.login_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections AS c
JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions AS s
    ON c.session_id = s.session_id
--WHERE c.session_id = @@SPID;
--WHERE status = 'sleeping'
ORDER BY c.connect_time ASC
```

Which gives the following:[image: Emtpy login name]
Please note the empty login name, I get a lot of similar connections...

Comment: can you map that to sys.connections dmv

Comment: also try :http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/tags/sp_5F00_whoisactive/default.aspx  sp_whoisactive

Comment: @TheGameiswar how can I do that? (mapping)

Comment: this should work:`select * from sys.dm_exec_connections ec
join
 sys.sysprocesses pc
on pc.spid=ec.session_id
`

Comment: also can you paste entire output of sys.processes

Comment: can you join this chat :http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145990/azure

Comment: Sorry we couldn't contnue at that time. If any body else  can help please advise. Please try to get in touch @TheGameiswar as well

Comment: you will need to add full output of sys.processes

Comment: I just tried to execute the query from SSMS without paging(to make it take more time), and I got 7 connections without a LoginName. So it's not the web app sending multiple requests for the same query.

Comment: @TheGameiswar please find a more detailed output above

Comment: The empty login names are a by-product of connection pooling.  Unused connections in the pool do not have a login name.

Comment: @StrayCatDBA Do you have any recommendation to solve the issue?

Comment: @Techy have you ever solved this issue ??